# Bayesian iterated expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, bayesian

Firstly i'm familiar with the law of iterated expectations i.e. $\mathbb{E}(\theta) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\theta|Y))$ in the Bayesian context we can think of $\mathbb{E}(\theta|Y)$ as the posterior expectation of the unknown parameter $\theta$.

The book that that i'm reading considers the normal-normal model. Where $\theta$ is normally distributed with fixed hyperparameters $\mu_0,\tau_0^2$ and the data $y|\theta \sim N(\theta,\sigma^2)$ where $\sigma$ is known.

I'm stuck on the following part of the book which looks at the posterior predictive distribution of $P(\tilde{y}|y)$

[image]

Equations 2.8 and 2.9 refer to the basic iterated expectation and variance rules. I'm confused as to how they have calculated the first equality in $\mathbb{E}(\tilde{y}|y)$? I.e why is $\mathbb{E}(\tilde{y}|y) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\tilde{y}|\theta,y)|y)$ can someone provide some justification or proof of this fact?

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly i'm familiar with the law of iterated expectations. $\mathsf E(\theta)=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(\theta\mid Y))$

> why is $\mathsf E(\tilde y\mid y)=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(\tilde y\mid θ,y)\mid y)$
> can someone provide some justification or proof of this fact?

It is called the Law of Iterated Expectation, because it is iterative. $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X)&=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y))\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y,Z)\mid Y))\end{align}$$

Comment: Wait do you have an extra expectation?

Comment: Yes. For that result to hold *for any* $X$ (measurable over the joined sigma algebra) is that    $\mathsf E(X\mid Y)=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y,Z)\mid Y)$ must hold too. And indeed that holds for the same reason $\mathsf E(X)=\mathsf E(X\mid Y)$ holds. Thus the Law is iterative.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Why $E(X|Y)=E(E(X|Y,Z)|Y)$?

Comment: We know $E(E(X|Y,Z)|Y)=\sum_{y}E(E(X|Y,Z)|Y=y)P(Y=y)$. Is it just $E(E(X|Y,Z)|Y)=\sum_{y}E(E(X|Y=y,Z))P(Y=y)=\sum_{y}E(E(X|Y=y,Z))P(Y=y)=EE(X|Y)$?

Comment: So we have $E(X|Y)=EE(X|Y, Z)=E(E(X|Y,Z)|Y)$?

Comment: Well, assuming we are dealing with discrete random variables: $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y)) &=\sum_y \mathsf P(Y{=}y)\sum_x (\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Y{=}y)\cdot x)\\&=\sum_y\mathsf P(Y{=}y)\sum_x (\sum_z\mathsf P(Z{=}z\mid Y{=}y)\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Y{=}y,Z{=}z)\cdot x)\\&=\sum_y\mathsf P(Y{=}y)\sum_z\mathsf P(Z{=}z\mid Y{=}y)\sum_x (\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid Y{=}y,Z{=}z)\cdot x)\\&=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Z,Y)\mid Y)) \end{align}$$